# Windows disappear but still in task manager. How to get them back?

Tags: windows, desktop

I have this problem now for a long time.
It happens that for example I have many Command prompt windows and notepad opened and suddenly I realize the windows are gone but the processes are still in Task manager.

Does anyone know what is going on. Did I press some kind of shortcut for this to happen.
Can I get them back somehow?

Comment: On windows 7 there's a box on the lower right hand corner of the desktop ... if you hover over it it hides all your windows (and they return when you mouse out). If you click it it hides them all until you click it again. Also, windows+m is a shortcut for minimise all windows.

Comment: No, it's not that simple. This is not minimizing.
They disappear from the taskbar but they are still alive in the Task Manager.

Comment: So not showing in the applications tab of task manager then? If that's the case it doesn't sound normal and I'd immediately suspect something untoward going on, such as malware or virus related stuff (I am a little paranoid). Maybe run a malware/virus scan?

Comment: To put it simple: If you open Task Manager the applications are not listed in Applications tab but they are still in the Processes tab.
For some reason they disappeared. It happens occasionally and to random applications that's why I thought I might have pressed something.

Comment: As standard I don't think that should happen, however I have used a program in the past that hides windows (I can't remember the name of it but it had a little cat icon in the taskbar right-hand set of icons) that can have a shortcut key assigned to hide all windows ... maybe it's something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit.
I started this software which caused the problems:
http://tribe.nu/Blockify.html